# java -jar xxx.jar working very well on Mac osx and Windows but I get the following error: "Error: Could not find or load main class" on raspberry pi

Tags: java, maven, jar, raspberry-pi3

java -jar xxx.jar (compiled with maven) working very well on Mac osx and Windows but  I get the following error: "Error: Could not find or load main class" on raspberry pi. Suggestions or Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It means `xxx.jar` does not contain Manifest file which has a main class (that contains main method) to start with. In this case, you have to mention in the command line as below

```
java -cp xxx.jar com.mypack.mymainclass
```

where your main method is in class `com.mypack.mymainclass`

Comment: can you check this file [link] (http://wikisend.com/download/765616/mavenproject1-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar)

Comment: @Liger Your JAR file contains a main method defined in Manifest. So it is running main method but it is missing some other class `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application`

Comment: what is your java version? 1.7?

Comment: it must be min 1.8 for javafx apps